# fontspec LuaTeX error

Tags: xetex, luatex, miktex, fontspec, texstudio

I have installed "ProTeX" with "TeXstudio 2.3" & "Miktex 2.9".
I get an error

```
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function
```

when I attempt to run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Hello world! 
\end{document}
```

MikTeX is said to come with some of this installed.

Answer (score 8):

You have to reconfig TeXstudio to use `lualatex` or `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` which is preconfigured in TeXstudio.  You can change it under `options`, then `commands`.

You can also use the command line to test whether for example `lualatex` is running. `lualatex test` will compile `test.tex` with `lualatex`.

Comment: 'comands' reads "latex -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex". How should it then read?

Comment: If you are pressing `F6` in running your `pdflatex`, replace `pdflatex` in `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` with either `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

Comment: Oh, I hope you don't mind. I think the comment was harmless enough. :)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm going to learn fast, with everyones help in this forum.

Comment: The update of TexStudio seems to have changed this...  I have to reset the default to `xelatex`.

Answer (score 7):

If you insist on TeXStudio you may now download [TeXStudio 2.4](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/). You can now set up your `xelatex` and `lualatex` commands with this version.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 but TeXStudio 2.4 must have the same features as the Windows version.

See in the picture below that there is already a separate box your `xelatex` and `lualatex` commands.

[image]

Now, in the `build` option, choose your default compiler. You may now choose either `xelatex` or `lualatex`. See picture below.

[image]

If you don't want to update just yet, you may look at my comment in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71442/16550).

But it is a hassle to keep on changing your default compiler. Some times it is better to just open `cmd` and run `xelatex myfile.tex` or `lualatex myfile.tex`. Just CD to your source folder before doing the compile.

Comment: I downloaded 2.4. I works great. I love the software improvements.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

You should compile the document with `xelatex` or `lualatex` command. 
For me, your document compiles with both with no errors.

Comment: I am an old pre-CP/M nerd. I don't use command line stuff if I can help it. Thanks for your answering my cry for help.

Answer (score 4):

Also in the MiKTeX Settings (Options window) under the “Formats” tab one must activate the creation of format files (needed for fonts!) for lualatex, luatex, xelatex and xetex:

[image: window screenshot]

Select every single of them, click on ‘Change…’ and in the dialogue window “Format Definition” deactivate ‘Exclude this format when updating all format files’.

Then, *very important*, go to the “General” tab and update all format files, what creates also the new ones, followed by a refresh of the filename data base (FNDB).

Comment: I have done the above plus exclude Latex, Pdflatex, "Update Formats", and have the same error.

Comment: @Optionparty: My answer is an addition to the others. You didn’t say anything to them. *But also important:* I’ve forgotten a second step, see my edit.