# Insert hyphenation point in BibTeX using PDFLaTeX and hyperref

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, pdftex, line-breaking, hyphenation

How to tell PDFLaTeX to make hyphenation in place where I want it to be?

I have my document file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{reference}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib_file}

\end{document}
```

and `bib_file.bib` file:

```
@misc{reference,
    title = {{Some dummy title in bib.}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html\#concurrency}},
    note = {Last access: 12.03.2013},
}
```

After building that file, the new line is places just after '.':

```
1st line: Some dummy title in bib. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.
2nd line: html#concurrency. Last access: 12.03.2013.
```

But I wanted to insert hyphenation point on other place, like:

```
1st line: Some dummy title in bib. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/
2nd line: relnotes/features.html#concurrency. Last access: 12.03.2013.
```

or even:

```
1st line: Some dummy title in bib. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/ <-/
2nd line: relnotes/features.html#concurrency. Last access: 12.03.2013.
```

`<-/` - is the *enter* arrow.

I tried to insert `{\-}` and `\-` into the url, but it adds in that place `\discretionary{-
}{}{}` text

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It's not clear to me that there's actually a problem that needs to be solved -- at least for the MWE you've given us: Given a page size of `A4` and margins of `2.5cm`, it's perfectly sound to break the long URL after `features.`, as the resulting line is neither overfull nor underfull (i.e., no big whitespaces). If you were to change the margins to `4cm`, say, you'd get a line break after `/docs/`.

Comment: Breaking just before extension (like php, html, jsp, ...) is not good at all. I wanted to tell [PDF]LaTeX/BibTeX where the breaking the line in the url is (in my opinion) the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71442/16550) already shows how to fine tune the line breaking of URL's by specifying `\UrlBreaks`, `\UrlBigBreaks`, and `\UrlNoBreaks`.

To get a carriage return symbol at breaking points, we specify the breaking points as `\UrlSpecials`, that include the symbol when a line break occurs there.

```
\usepackage{dingbat}  % for \carriagereturn symbol
\newcommand{\urllb}{\discretionary{\carriagereturn}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{}    % no standard breaking points
\renewcommand{\UrlBigBreaks}{}
\renewcommand{\UrlSpecials}{\do\.{\mathchar`\.\urllb}%
                            \do\/{\mathchar`\/\urllb}%
                            \do\@{\mathchar`\@\urllb}%
                            \do\\{\mathchar`\\\urllb}%
                            \do\-{\mathchar`\-\urllb}%
                            \do\#{\mathchar`\#\urllb}}% and so on
```

To specify breaking points by hand we use a symbol that hopefully won't occur in any URL like a star `*`, and make it a break URL's like the above symbols, but vanishing from the string:

```
\renewcommand{\UrlSpecials}{\do\*{\urllb}}
```

In order to have correct links with this solution the star needs to be filtered out from the link, too. We use the gorgeous [solution of Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103872/21591):

```
\makeatletter
\def\strip@star#1*#2\@strip@star{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\strip@star@result\expandafter{\strip@star@result#1}%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
        \def\strip@star@temp{#2}%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\strip@star\expandafter\strip@star@temp
        \expandafter\@strip@star
    \fi
}
\patchcmd{\hyper@linkurl}{\Hy@pstringdef\Hy@pstringURI{#2}}{%
    \def\strip@star@result{}%
    \expandafter\strip@star#2*\@strip@star
    \Hy@pstringdef\Hy@pstringURI{\strip@star@result}%
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Of course, both solutions can be mixed, i.e., we can specify the normal breaking points as `\UrlSpecials`, as well as the star for additional hand made breaking points.

Complete code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{reference,
    title = {{Some dummy title in bib.}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://docs.*oracle.com/*javase/*1.5.0/*docs/*rel*notes/*fea*tures.html#*concur*rency}},
    note = {Last access: 12.03.2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{dingbat}  % for \carriagereturn symbol
\newcommand{\urllb}{\discretionary{\carriagereturn}{}{}}
%% original breaking points of url package
% \def\UrlBreaks{\do\.\do\@\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]%
%  \do\)\do\,\do\?\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#}%
% \def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\:\do@url@hyp}%

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlNoBreaks}{\do\.} % do not break after dot '.'
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{}    % no standard breaking points
\renewcommand{\UrlBigBreaks}{}
\renewcommand{\UrlSpecials}{\do\_{\mathchar`\_\urllb}%
                            \do\/{\mathchar`\/\urllb}%
                            \do\@{\mathchar`\@\urllb}%
                            \do\\{\mathchar`\\\urllb}%
                            \do\-{\mathchar`\-\urllb}%
                            \do\#{\mathchar`\#\urllb}}% and so on
% \renewcommand{\UrlSpecials}{\do\*{\urllb}}

%% solution of Qrrbrbirlbel, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103870/21591
\makeatletter
\def\strip@star#1*#2\@strip@star{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\strip@star@result\expandafter{\strip@star@result#1}%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
        \def\strip@star@temp{#2}%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\strip@star\expandafter\strip@star@temp
        \expandafter\@strip@star
    \fi
}
\patchcmd{\hyper@linkurl}{\Hy@pstringdef\Hy@pstringURI{#2}}{%
    \def\strip@star@result{}%
    \expandafter\strip@star#2*\@strip@star
    \Hy@pstringdef\Hy@pstringURI{\strip@star@result}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
This is text with \cite{reference}.

Automatic breaking with carriage return symbol:

Text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#concurrency}

Text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#concurrency}

Text text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#concurrency}

Text text text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#concurrency}

Text text text text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#concurrency}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#concurrency}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\UrlSpecials}{\do\*{\urllb}}
Hand tuned URL breaking:

Text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.*oracle.com/*javase/*1.5.0/*docs/*rel*notes/*fea*tures.html#concur*rency}

Text text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.*oracle.com/*javase/*1.5.0/*docs/*rel*notes/*fea*tures.html#concur*rency}

Text text text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.*oracle.com/*javase/*1.5.0/*docs/*rel*notes/*fea*tures.html#concur*rency}

Text text text text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.*oracle.com/*javase/*1.5.0/*docs/*rel*notes/*fea*tures.html#concur*rency}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text
\url{http://docs.*oracle.com/*javase/*1.5.0/*docs/*rel*notes/*fea*tures.html#concur*rency}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{faramir2}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: sample output]

All hail to Qrrbrbirlbel for the hard part.

Answer (score 7):

If you load package `hyperref` or package `url` LaTeX is able to find proper breaking points for an unmissleading hyphenation.  As a result of this it often happen, that you get big white spaces in an justified text.  It is not a good idea to insert in an url an additional `-` sign to mark a hyphenation. The reader does not know whether the `-` belongs to the url or is only a hyphenation sign. Urls are best hyphenated after a `/`, `.`etc.

I suggest to use package `ragged2e` and to use the command `\raggedright` to get a left justified bibliography.  All the bibliographys I did this way looked very well!

Edit: I updated the MWE with a peace of code copied from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url?rq=1) and got the linebreak in the url in that way you want.  But keep in mind: with this solution LaTeX decides were to break the url, not you with a special character.

Try this MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{reference,
    title = {{Some dummy title in bib.}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html\#concurrency}},
    note = {Last access: 12.03.2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url?rq=1
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\g@addto@macro{\UrlNoBreaks}{\do\.} % do not break after dot '.'
\makeatother

\usepackage[%
  newcommands     % \RaggedRight=\raggedright etc. 
 ,newparameters   % use default settings of ragged2e
]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{reference}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
{\raggedright  % group to end left justification after bib
\bibliography{\jobname}
}              % ends group for left justified bibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run your MWE on the bib entry provided by the OP, I get a line break *between* the entry's title and the URL string (which now fits into the textblock without need for further linebreaks). This is probably not the desired outcome. If you replace `\raggedright` with `\RaggedRight` (the command provided by the `ragged2e` package that allows for some hyphenation), you'll get a linebreak after `features.`, which is exactly the same result as if `ragged2e` wasn't loaded in the first place.

Comment: Simply loading `ragged2e` doesn't change the definition of `\raggedright`. You either need to use `\RaggedRight` or `\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}` to get the redefined `\raggedright` if you want to benefit from `ragged2e`.

Comment: Thank you but this don't resolve my problem - how to tell LaTeX where to break the url to make url best readable. What is more - I wanted to make an "enter arrow" (↵ - `&#x21b5;`) in place where the url is divided into two or more lines.

Comment: Thank you very much. I helps me to create:
`\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlNoBreaks}{\do\.}
\makeatother` so the break is not after dot and looks better (.). I don't know how to insert hyphenation character in the url (and make it like \hookleftarrow), but I think that is too hard for me now.