# Removing character from a hyperref link

Tags: hyperref

I would like to suppress a character from a `hyperref` link that is built via `\url`, but the textual representation should keep that character. For example, if the character is `*`, I want `\url{http://tex.stackexchange*.com}` act as `\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange*.com}`.

An embarrassingly failing attempt to hack the `\hyper@linkurl` macro is given in the MWE, just to show some effort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\hyper@linkurl{%
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`\*\relax
    \lowercase{\def~}{}%
    \catcode`\*\active
    \lccode`\~=0\relax
    \my@hyper@linkurl
}
\def\my@hyper@linkurl#1#2{%
   \edef\x{\toks0={#2}}\x
   \Hy@pstringdef\Hy@pstringURI{\the\toks0}%
   \hyper@chars
   \leavevmode
    \pdfstartlink
      attr{%
        \Hy@setpdfborder
        \ifx\@pdfhightlight\@empty
        \else
          /H\@pdfhighlight
        \fi
        \ifx\@urlbordercolor\relax
        \else
          /C[\@urlbordercolor]%
        \fi
      }%
      user{%
       /Subtype/Link%
       \ifHy@pdfa /F 4\fi
       /A<<%
         /Type/Action%
         /S/URI%
         /URI(\Hy@pstringURI)%
         \ifHy@href@ismap
           /IsMap true%
         \fi
         \Hy@href@nextactionraw
       >>%
      }%
      \relax
    \Hy@colorlink\@urlcolor#1\Hy@xspace@end
    \close@pdflink
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\url{http://tex.stackexchange*.com}
\end{document}
```

This is trying to make the star active, and let it be replaced by an empty group in the assignment to `toks0`, but it does not work. It also does not feel right to replicate so much code from `hyperref`. What is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Would it be that bad to just create your own `\Url` macro?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel What do you have in mind? A macro that does all the catcode juggling that hyperref does to get everything printed? Would that be any easier?

Comment: Could you, please, write a bit, why is not possible to use the `\href` version? _(Also, I actually would be interested in the purpose of your aim.)_

Comment: @Speravir The `\url` are coming from `bbl` files, formed from user provided URLs. So they are pretty much given. The * shall remain in the link text to be treated with `\UrlSpecial` for line breaking.

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t get it: Why do you want to show wrong links in your document? Just for line breaking? What is bad on a solution similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10419 ?

Comment: @Speravir Of course the star will not be printed, but handled with `\UrlSpecial`. Herbert's solution is all fine, but what I ultimately want to achieve is selective line breaking of the link text, e.g., allow breaks after some periods, say, but not after all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `etoolbox` package, patching of `\hyper@linkurl` seems easy and is more reliable than the my custom `\URL` definition (see [a previous version of this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/103872/1)).

This allows to use `#` and `&` in URLs.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\strip@star#1*#2\@strip@star{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\strip@star@result\expandafter{\strip@star@result#1}%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
        \def\strip@star@temp{#2}%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\strip@star\expandafter\strip@star@temp
        \expandafter\@strip@star
    \fi
}
\patchcmd{\hyper@linkurl}{\Hy@pstringdef\Hy@pstringURI{#2}}{%
    \def\strip@star@result{}%
    \expandafter\strip@star#2*\@strip@star
    \Hy@pstringdef\Hy@pstringURI{\strip@star@result}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\url{http://tex*.stack*exchange*.com#anchorwithfun:$&}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very good. But this approach removes only the first occurrence of the character, right? And it can not really be extended for all occurrences, right?

Comment: @mafp No, it removes every occurrence, hence the recursive call to `\strip@star` after checking that `#2` is not empty. I’ve added a patch for `\hyper@linkurl` which seems to work. Of course, the URL needs to be brace-less and should not have any special characters in it, otherwise all bets are off.

Comment: Whoa, the patching works with URLs containing #,~,=,?. That's it!