# Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, urls

I have some long URLs which doesn't contain special "line break characters" like "-" or "/". How can I automatically break these URLs?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{dingbat}  % for \carriagereturn symbol
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{%
\do\/\do\d%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{bachelorarbeit_lit.bib}
@ONLINE{java96,
    author = {{Joe Black}},
    title = {Foobar 1.0},
    year = {1996},
    month = {1},
    url = {http://www.aaa.bb.cccc.dh/uploads/dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd.pdf},
    urldate = {2011-03-02},
    sortname = {Sun},
    keywords = {www}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bachelorarbeit_lit}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{java96}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**edit**

I don't know why but it still doesn't work. Is there an option to automatically break long URLs. I don't care where the break is but it should be done automatically. Even if I manually specify the "breaking character" it doesn't work (as the example shows).

Comment: Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102152/insert-hyphenation-point-in-bibtex-using-pdflatex-and-hyperref/102168#102168?  Or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126702/url-linebreaks-w-o-sloppy  Does it help?

Comment: I have played now some time with this problem but the other solutions don't help.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Hacking `\UrlBreaks` is not needed for `\url` inside the bibliography of `biblatex`. Package `biblatex` uses `\biburlsetup` and has already added lots of characters. The breaking at some character classes is controlled by counters. From the [documentation of `biblatex`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), "4.10.3 User-definable Lengths and Counters":

> **`biburlnumpenalty`:** If this counter is set to a value greater than zero, `biblatex` will permit linebreaks after numbers in all strings
>   formatted with the `\url` command from the `url` package. This will
>   affect URLs and DOIs in the bibliography. The breakpoints will be
>   penalized by the value of this counter. If URLs and/or DOIs in the
>   bibliography run into the margin, try setting this counter to a value
>   greater than zero but less than 10000 (you normally want to use a high
>   value like 9000). Setting the counter to zero disables this feature.
>   This is the default setting.
>
> **`biburlucpenalty`:** Similar to `biburlnumpenalty`, except that it will add a breakpoint after all uppercase letters.
>
> **`biburllcpenalty`:** Similar to `biburlnumpenalty`, except that it will add a breakpoint after all lowercase letters.

An example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bachelorarbeit_lit.bib}
@ONLINE{java96,
    author = {{Joe Black}},
    title = {Foobar 1.0},
    year = {1996},
    month = {1},
    url = {http://www.aaa.bb.cccc.dh/uploads/dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd.pdf},
    urldate = {2011-03-02},
    sortname = {Sun},
    keywords = {www}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}

%%% --- The following two lines are what needs to be added --- %%%
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

\bibliography{bachelorarbeit_lit}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{java96}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I use bibtex as the backend, but the given code does not work on mactex. In MikTex, I was able to compile. Any solution for mactex?

Comment: @max I just run the example using option `backend=bibtex` and using `bibtex` instead of `biber` and it just worked. I cannot test on MacTeX. But since you have a working and non-working case, you can investigate, compare versions, ...

Comment: I manually updated the distribution and now it is working. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice solution. I was using the `\sloppy` (and similar) command but the problem was that it didn't insert a line break inside strings containing only letters which lead to a partial fix.

Comment: Coming to this 10 years late... Is the same functionality provided for DOI links that are automatically generated from a doi bibtex entry? It's certainly not automatically line breaking for me.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll All kind of URL links (doi, url, ...) should be supported, because they are using `\url` or `\href` with `\nolinkurl` that all expand to the macro `\Url` of package `url`  with its penaly settings that are set by `biblatex` by its internal setup hooks (`\biburlsetup`). I suggest that you ask a new question with a minimal example that shows the problems of line breaking of the DOI links with your settings.

Comment: what is the package library for `biburllcpenalty ` ?  I am getting following error: `! Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid for 'biblatex'.`

Answer (score 27):

There is another way (SHORTER) of doing that: just put the entry below before the `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
```

This allows to have your customized (or required!) bibliography style (e.g. `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`) unchanged.

Comment: The example URL doesn't contain suitably placed `/` or `-` on which to break, so it's not clear why this should work.

Comment: also check out the `xurl` package

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the accepted answer did not work for me (maybe old package versions, which I can't update by myself here at work). Anyway, since I use **LuaLaTeX** to compile my document, here another solution (found at https://yingtongli.me/blog/2016/01/08/breaking-urls-anywhere-in-lualatex-even.html):

Create a document `betterurl.lua` with following content:

```
function betterurl(text)
  label = text:gsub(".", "%1\\allowbreak{}")

  label = label:gsub("~", "\\textasciitilde")
  label = label:gsub("&", "\\&")
  label = label:gsub("/", "/")
  label = label:gsub("-", "-")

  url = text

  tex.print("\\href{" .. url .. "}{" .. label .. "}")

end
```

and add

```
\RequirePackage{luacode}
  \luaexec{require("path/to/betterurl")}
  \renewcommand{\url}[1]{\luadirect{
    betterurl(\luastringN{#1})
  }}
```

to your preamble. Note that you do not need to add the file extension `.lua`.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: So far, this is the only option that displayed everything correctly, but when clicking, the link, an "-" is inserted, so the URL is wrong - so still not working well. Note: For TeXstudio, use Menu > Tools > Commands > LuaLaTeX. And I put it after "\usepackage{url}", otherwise it will throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

All this didn't work for me.
My solution works, but it's not pretty - kind of a last resort (visually it fits, but it isn't automatic).

**Be aware that I used the `bibtex` format, which could be the problem too.**

You can directly define the url inside your `references.bib` (or however you named it).
You might have something like this:

```
@misc{a_very_consice_key,
  title = {A very nice title},
  urldate = {2023-11-19},
  howpublished = {https://www.example.com/aaaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbb/ccccccccc/ddddddddd},
}
```

Do this:

```
@misc{a_very_consice_key,
  title = {A very nice title},
  urldate = {2023-11-19},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.example.com/aaaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbb/ccccccccc/ddddddddd}},
}
```

this already works ... but might add `\texttt{}` formatting that doesn't fit the rest of your literature (for me it didn't fit), so I added a few things.

in your packages.tex (or whereever you define your packages):

```latex
\usepackage{hyperref}  % <- I had that 
\usepackage{xurl}      % <- I added that
```

It works without it too (changes the breakpoints a little - maybe you need it)

Now we define a new command (I have it in my `definitions.tex`)

```latex
\newcommand{\normalurl}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\UrlFont\relax
    \urlstyle{same} % use current font style
    \url{#1}%
    \endgroup
}
```

...and use our new `\normalurl` command instead of the `\url` command inside of our `.bib` file:

```
@misc{a_very_consice_key,
  title = {A very nice title},
  urldate = {2023-11-19},
  howpublished = {\normalurl{https://www.example.com/aaaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbb/ccccccccc/ddddddddd}},
}
```

---

I don't understand why this is a problem at all. Maybe someone with more experience can create a function from this that doesn't break `\url` and just automatically fixes the urls inside the bibliography?

Can't really have random dashes (`-`) in URLs. Especially if the `biber` package adds `\href`s after the fact.

Comment: If you are indeed using `biblatex` (as the other answers assume, but is not *entirely* clere here), then `howpublished` is not the best field for the URL. All good `biblatex` styles support a `url` field for URLs and the formatting of those URLs can be configured as shown in the other answer. This can even be combined with a simple `\urlstyle{same}` in the preamble to lose the `\ttfamily` look. `biblatex` will not insert dashes that weren't there when URLs are broken and will link to the correct URL at all times.

Comment: whoops, I was wondering about that too "Why is that not 'url'?", but I blindly trusted Zotero.

Turned out, I exported as `bibtex`. I still have that problem though (somewhere else). Maybe does the same mistake as me and ends up here. I'm going to put a disclaimer at the top...