# Bibliography exceeds the page boundaries

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, urls

there is something wrong with the format of my bibliography. As you can see in the picture, a reference (and a few more in the next non visible page) exceeds the boundaries:

[image]

I do not understand why and it's really an irregular behaviour.
My document class is:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.3 (25/3/16)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[11pt, english, singlespacing,headsepline, 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
```

And this is the whole MastersDoctoralThesis.cls

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CLASS DEFINITION AND PARAMETERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\newcommand{\classname}{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\ProvidesClass{\classname}[2016/03/25 v1.4 LaTeXTemplates.com]
\providecommand{\baseclass}{book}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\newbool{nolistspace}
\newbool{chapteroneline}
\newbool{listtoc}
\newbool{toctoc}
\newbool{parskip}
\newbool{hyperrefsupport}
\booltrue{hyperrefsupport}
\newbool{headsepline}

\DeclareOption{nohyperref}{\boolfalse{hyperrefsupport}}
\DeclareOption{nolistspacing}{\booltrue{nolistspace}}
\DeclareOption{liststotoc}{\booltrue{listtoc}}
\DeclareOption{chapterinoneline}{\booltrue{chapteroneline}}
\DeclareOption{toctotoc}{\booltrue{toctoc}}
\DeclareOption{parskip}{\booltrue{parskip}}
\DeclareOption{headsepline}{\booltrue{headsepline}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{\baseclass}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CLASS OPTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\ifbool{parskip}{\RequirePackage{parskip}} % If the parskip option is passed to the class, require the parskip package 

\newcommand{\abovechapterspace}{\vspace*{50pt}}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\abovechapterspace}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\abovechapterspace}{}{}
\newcommand{\autodot}{}
\newcommand{\mdtChapapp}{}
\ifbool{chapteroneline}{%
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
        \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
        \fi
    }{%
        \if@mainmatter
        \Huge\bfseries \mdtChapapp\thechapter\autodot\enspace
        \fi
    }{}{}
}

\ifbool{listtoc}{% If the liststotoc option has been passed to the class, add the lists to the table of contents
    \patchcmd{\listoftables}{\@starttoc{lot}}{%
        \addchaptertocentry{\listtablename}\@starttoc{lot}}{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\@starttoc{lof}}{%
        \addchaptertocentry{\listfigurename}\@starttoc{lof}}{}{}%
}

\ifbool{toctoc}{% If the toctotoc options has been passed to the class, add the table of contents to the table of contents
    \patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}{%
        \addchaptertocentry{\contentsname}\@starttoc{toc}}{}{}%
}

\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}

% If the option `nolistspacing' is given, the spacing in the different lists is reduced to single spacing. This option is only useful, if the spacing of the document has been changed to onehalfspacing or doublespacing.
\ifbool{nolistspace}{
    \patchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
        \@starttoc{lof}}{%
            \begingroup%
            \singlespace\@starttoc{lof}\endgroup%
        }{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\listoftables}{%
        \@starttoc{lot}}{%
            \begingroup%
            \singlespace\@starttoc{lot}\endgroup%
        }{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{%
        \@starttoc{toc}}{%
            \begingroup%
            \singlespace\@starttoc{toc}\endgroup%
        }{}{}%
}{}

% Addchap provides unnumbered chapters with an entry in the table of contents as well as an updated header
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\addchap}{ s o m }{%
    \chapter*{#3}%
    \markboth{}{}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    }{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
            \addchaptertocentry{#3}%
            \markboth{\MakeMarkcase{#3}}{\MakeMarkcase{#3}}%
        }{%
            \addchaptertocentry{#2}%
            \markboth{\MakeMarkcase{#2}}{\MakeMarkcase{#2}}%
        }%
    }%
}%

\ProvideDocumentCommand{\addsec}{ s o m }{%
    \section*{#3}%
    \markright{}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    }{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3}%
            \markright{\MakeMarkcase{#3}}%%
        }{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
            \markright{\MakeMarkcase{#2}}%
        }%
    }%
}%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REQUIRED PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{babel} % Required for automatically changing names of document elements to languages besides english

\RequirePackage{scrbase} % Required for handling language-dependent names of sections/document elements

\RequirePackage{scrhack} % Loads fixes for various packages

\RequirePackage{setspace} % Required for changing line spacing

\RequirePackage{longtable} % Required for tables that span multiple pages (used in the symbols, abbreviations and physical constants pages)

\RequirePackage{siunitx} % Required for \SI commands

\RequirePackage{graphicx} % Required to include images
\graphicspath{{Figures/}{./}} % Specifies where to look for included images

\RequirePackage{booktabs} % Required for better table rules

\RequirePackage{caption} % Required for customising the captions
\captionsetup{justification=centerlast,font=small,labelfont=sc,margin=50pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\checktoopen}{% New command to move content to the next page which prints to the next odd page if twosided mode is active  
\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
\ifdef{\phantomsection}{\phantomsection}{}% The \phantomsection command is necessary for hyperref to jump to the correct page
}

\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{--------------------}}
\newcommand\tttypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % New command to make the lines in the title page
\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{.8\textwidth}{.4pt}} % New command for a rule to be used under figures

\renewcommand{\abovechapterspace}{\vspace*{10pt}} % Reduce the whitespace above a chapter heading

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % The depth to which the document sections are printed to the table of contents
\providecommand\addchaptertocentry[1]{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    headheight=4ex,
    includehead,
    includefoot
}

\raggedbottom

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PENALTIES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\doublehyphendemerits=10000 % No consecutive line hyphens
\brokenpenalty=10000 % No broken words across columns/pages
\widowpenalty=9999 % Almost no widows at bottom of page
\clubpenalty=9999 % Almost no orphans at top of page
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999 % Almost never break footnotes

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADERS AND FOOTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
\clearpairofpagestyles%
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Outer header
}
\ifoot{}% Inner footer
\ofoot{}% Outer footer
\pagestyle{thesisSimple}
\providepairofpagestyles[thesisSimple]{thesis}{%
\automark*[section]{}%
}
\providepairofpagestyles[thesisSimple]{review}{%
    \ofoot[\ttitle/\authorname]{\ttitle/\authorname}
    \ifoot[\today]{\today}
}
\pagestyle{thesis}
\ifbool{headsepline}{\KOMAoption{headsepline}{true}}{}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[\ClassError{\classname}{Package `fancyhdr' is
incompatible\MessageBreak with this class}{The pagesyles are defined 
using package `scrlayer-scrpage', please consult the\MessageBreak 
KOMA-script documentation for details.}]{fancyhdr}


\newcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{empty}
\newcommand{\blankpagestyle}[1]{\def\blank@p@gestyle{#1}}

\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{\blank@p@gestyle}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEFINE CUSTOM THESIS INFORMATION COMMANDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def\authorname{}
\def\ttitle{}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\thesistitle}[1]{\def\@title{#1}\def\ttitle{#1}}
\newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\def\degreename{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\author}[1]{\def\authorname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\addresses}[1]{\def\addressname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\def\univname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\subjectname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\def\keywordnames{#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DECLARATION PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\authorshipname}{Declaration of Authorship}
\providecaptionname{american,australian,british,canadian,english,newzealand,UKenglish,USenglish}{\authorshipname}{Declaration of Authorship} % Declaration of Authorship text for English countries
\providecaptionname{german,ngerman,austrian,naustrian}{\authorshipname}{Eidesstattliche Erkl\"arung} % Declaration of Authorship text for Germanic countries

\newenvironment{declaration}{
    \checktoopen
    \tttypeout{\authorshipname}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \null\vfil
    {\noindent\huge\bfseries\authorshipname\par\vspace{10pt}}
}{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEDICATION PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
    \checktoopen
    \tttypeout{Dedicatory}
    \null\vfil
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{center}{\Large\slshape #1}\end{center}
    \vfil\null
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\byname}{by}
\providecaptionname{german,ngerman,austrian,naustrian}{\byname}{von}
\providecaptionname{american,australian,british,canadian,english,newzealand,UKenglish,USenglish}{\byname}{by}
\newenvironment{abstract}{
    %\checktoopen
    %\tttypeout{\abstractname}
    %\null\vfil
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    %\begin{flushright}
    %{\normalsize \MakeUppercase{\univname} \par} % University name in capitals
    %\bigskip
    %{\huge\textit{\abstractname} \par}
    %\bigskip
    %{\normalsize \facname \par} % Faculty name
    %{\normalsize \deptname \par} % Department name
    %\bigskip
    %{\normalsize \degreename\par} % Degree name
    %\bigskip
    %{\normalsize\bfseries \@title \par} % Thesis title
    %\medskip
    %{\normalsize \byname{} \authorname \par} % Author name
    %\bigskip
    %\end{flushright}
}
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABBREVIATIONS PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\abbrevname}{List of Abbreviations}
\providecaptionname{english,british,american}{\abbrevname}{List of Abbreviations}
\providecaptionname{ngerman,german,austrian,naustrian}{\abbrevname}{Abk\"urzungsverzeichnis}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{abbreviations}{ m }{%
    \ifbool{nolistspace}{\begingroup\singlespacing}{}
    \ifbool{listtoc}{\addchap{\abbrevname}}{\addchap*{\abbrevname}}
    \begin{longtable}{#1}
}{%
\end{longtable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1} % Don't count this table as one of the document tables
\ifbool{nolistspace}{\endgroup}{}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PHYSICAL CONSTANTS PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\constantsname}{Physical Constants}
\providecaptionname{english,british,american}{\constantsname}{Physical Constants}
\providecaptionname{ngerman,german,austrian,naustrian}{\constantsname}{Physikalische Konstanten}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{constants}{ m }{%
    \ifbool{nolistspace}{\begingroup\singlespacing}{}
    \ifbool{listtoc}{\addchap{\constantsname}}{\addchap*{\constantsname}}
    \begin{longtable}{#1}
}{%
\end{longtable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1} % Don't count this table as one of the document tables
\ifbool{nolistspace}{\endgroup}{}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SYMBOLS PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\symbolsname}{List of Symbols}
\providecaptionname{english,british,american}{\symbolsname}{List of Symbols}
\providecaptionname{ngerman,german,austrian,naustrian}{\symbolsname}{Symbolverzeichnis}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{symbols}{ m }{%
    \ifbool{nolistspace}{\begingroup\singlespacing}{}
    \ifbool{listtoc}{\addchap{\symbolsname}}{\addchap*{\symbolsname}}
    \begin{longtable}{#1}
}{%
\end{longtable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1} % Don't count this table as one of the document tables
\ifbool{nolistspace}{\endgroup}{}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\acknowledgementname}{Acknowledgements}
\providecaptionname{american,australian,british,canadian,english,newzealand,UKenglish,USenglish} {\acknowledgementname}{Acknowledgements} % Acknowledgement text for English countries
\providecaptionname{german,ngerman,austrian,naustrian}{\acknowledgementname}{Danksagung} % Acknowledgement text for Germanic countries

\NewDocumentEnvironment{acknowledgements}{}{%
\checktoopen
\tttypeout{\acknowledgementname}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}{\huge\textit{\textbf{\acknowledgementname}}\par}\end{center}
}
{
\vfil
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\ifbool{hyperrefsupport}{% If the nohyperref class option has not been specified
\AfterPackage{biblatex}{ % Load the hyperref package after the biblatex package for compatibility 
\RequirePackage{hyperref} % Required for customising links and the PDF
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=0,
hypertexnames=false,
colorlinks=true, % Set to false to disable coloring links
citecolor=black, % The color of citations
linkcolor=black, % The color of references to document elements (sections, figures, etc)
urlcolor=black, % The color of hyperlinks (URLs) but also the first page title, headers and so on
pdfstartview={FitV},
unicode,
breaklinks=true,
}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{% If there is an explicit linebreak in a section heading (or anything printed to the pdf-bookmarks), it is replaced by a space
   \let\\\space%
}
}
}{%nothing
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\endinput
% lazyLizardTracer
```

Maybe you can help me finding the solution? Thank you in advance!

Comment: See also [Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134191/35864). Note that the github URL does not look as if it was set in the `url` field, so it does not get the proper treatment.

Comment: Can you please add a link to that class you use?  And please complete your code snippet with `\documentclass` to be compilable, showing us how you build the bibliography.  And add only the bib entries to your question, which gives you problems (the shown 1, 6 and 11 for example).

Comment: The original class file is licensed under LPPL, you removed that as well as the maintainer information and basically put the whole class under CC3.0. That is not ok. Please add that block or remove the class alltogether (leaving just a link to where it can be found).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134191/line-breaks-of-long-urls-in-bibliography/134281#134281)

Comment: Did the linked question help you?

Comment: @moewe unfortunately not. By applying the changes, somehow the result didn't chage

Comment: I'm afraid in that case you will have to provide a [proper MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Just provide a link to where we can find the `.cls` file you are using and show us a complete (yet short) document where the problem occurs.

Comment: By the way, i was serious about the license stuff. Please add the original license or remove the class file and just leave a link.

Comment: @Johannes_B sorry I didn't really understand what you meant.. That's why I didn't apply any changes. Do you mean by any chance the comments I added before the documentclass?

Comment: I meant the comments at the top of the class file, not main.tex. But that is good enough, thanks :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, we still don't have an MWE, without that your question is near-impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `url` package then tweak how much you're willing the lines to be broken:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu
```

Comment: I tried this, I saw it also in other answers. But somehow it doesn't change anything