# Proper Formating and Spacing in bibliography with Url

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have I bibliography where I have Author, Title and I want to provide an external link . I use BibTeX and I make an entry like this:

```
@misc{DLVS,
    author    = "KDnuggets",
    title     = "Data lake vs Data warehouses: Key differences",
    note      = {\url{https://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/09/data-lake-vs-data-warehouse-key-differences.html}}
}
```

but my bibliography is formatted like this

[image]

which is far from optimal. Is there a way to improve the formatting? For example how can we avoid the big gaps and split the url in two lines? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please, see the answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134281/69174
The question is very similar.

Comment: You need to load the `url` package with the option `hyphens`. (By default, long URL strings aren't line-broken at hyphens.)