# How to cite part of online entry (website chapter) in BibLaTex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, online

I want to cite a part of a web page. Something analogical to a chapter of a book.
But from the [documentation](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), the `@online` entry only has `subtitle` and `titleaddon` fields which seem somehow relevant, but from my understanding serve to display a title referencing the whole article, not part of it.

([The website I want to reference](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#Whatis).) What I'm currently doing is:

```
@online{parallel-computing,
    author = "Blaise Barney",
    title = "Introduction to Parallel Computing",
    url = "https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#Whatis"
}
```

And I'd like to specifically refer to the part *What is Parallel Computing?*, which I'm currently referencing with the URL (don't know if that's appropriate).

Comment: I guess you could just use `@inbook`. It should look OK. Use `author`, `title`, `booktitle`, `url`, and `date`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular example (and I guess for most website with their own URL) I would just use `@online` to refer to the complete website and give the 'section'  in the postnote of the citation to refer to the specific part. Much like one normally adds the complete `@book` to the bibliography, but only cites a specific page.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{parallel-computing,
  author       = {Blaise Barney},
  title        = {Introduction to Parallel Computing},
  url          = {https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp},
  urldate      = {2019-08-06},
  organization = {Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \autocite[section \enquote{What is Parallel Computing?}]{parallel-computing}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem ipsum (Barney 2019, section ‘What is Parallel Computing?’).//Barney, Blaise (2019). Introduction to Parallel Computing. Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory. url: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp (visited on 06/08/2019).]

To me the most natural, self-contained unit in this case just appears to be the complete website.

---

If you insist that the specific section be referenced in the bibliography, you can follow  [David Purton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/87678/david-purton)'s [advice from the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503036/how-to-cite-part-of-online-entry-website-chapter-in-biblatex#comment1270749_503036) and (ab)use the `@inbook` entry type.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{barney:whatis,
  author       = {Blaise Barney},
  booktitle    = {Introduction to Parallel Computing},
  title        = {What is Parallel Computing?},
  url          = {https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#Whatis},
  urldate      = {2019-08-06},
  publisher    = {Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{barney:whatis}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem ipsum (Barney 2019).//Barney, Blaise (2019). ‘What is Parallel Computing?’ In: Introduction to Parallel Computing. Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory. url: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#Whatis (visited on 06/08/2019).]

---

Of course it would be possible to define a new entry type called `@inonline` that relates to `@online` as `@inbook` relates to `@book`. At the moment I doubt this is worth the effort, but it is most certainly doable. See [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) for a starter.

Alternatively, [Bib Formatting Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457593/35864) shows how you could add `maintitle` to `@online` entries so that you could have something like

```
@online{barney:whatis,
  author       = {Blaise Barney},
  maintitle    = {Introduction to Parallel Computing},
  title        = {What is Parallel Computing?},
  url          = {https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#Whatis},
  urldate      = {2019-08-06},
  organization = {Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory},
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty exhaustive yet comprehensible answer. I'll now (ab)use the comments section by saying thank you for that.