# use \path instead of \verb in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, verbatim, url

Noting that `\path` can be made to wrap arbitrary text as per [Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url), I would like to use `\path` instead of `\verb` inside of biblatex for the "verbatim" fields.

This would mean overriding both `\verb` and `\endverb`, see for example these lines in the `.bbl` file generated from the MWE below.

```
  \verb{file}
  \verb /Users/joe/Weholdthesetruthstobeself-evidentthatallmenarecreatedequalthattheyareendowedbytheirCreatorwithcertainunalienableRightsthatamongtheseareLifeLibertyandthepursuitofHappiness/dec.txt
  \endverb
```

I'm confused about how that would work syntactically.

The image here shows desired line wrapping on "Path"; the (nice) behaviour for a  file name with lots of underscores; and the (not very nice) behaviour for file name without underscores.

[image]

Source code for the above:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=reading,
            entryhead=true,
            entrykey=false,
            natbib,
            hyperref=false,
            url=false,
            doi=false,
            %style=apa,
            sorting=nyt,
            isbn=false,
            %backref=true,
            firstinits=true,
            minnames=13,
            maxnames=35,
            minbibnames=10,
            maxbibnames=100,
            parentracker=true,
            defernumbers=true,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{XXXXXX,
  author = {PQR},
  booktitle = {BBC},
  keywords = {LLM},
  title = {ARP},
  year = {2010a},
  file = {/Users/joe/We_hold_these_truths_to_be_self-evident_that_all_men_are_created_equal_that_they_are_endowed_by_their_Creator_with_certain_unalienable_Rights_that_among_these_are_Life_Liberty_and_the_pursuit_of_Happiness/dec.txt},
}

@inproceedings{YYYYYYYY,
  author = {PQR},
  booktitle = {BBC},
  keywords = {LLM},
  title = {ARP},
  year = {2010b},
  file = {/Users/joe/Weholdthesetruthstobeself-evidentthatallmenarecreatedequalthattheyareendowedbytheirCreatorwithcertainunalienableRightsthatamongtheseareLifeLibertyandthepursuitofHappiness/dec.txt},
}
\end{filecontents}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks%  save the current one
  \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
  \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
  \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
  \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
  \do\Y\do\Z}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Path: \path{/Users/joe/Weholdthesetruthstobeself-evidentthatallmenarecreatedequalthattheyareendowedbytheirCreatorwithcertainunalienableRightsthatamongtheseareLifeLibertyandthepursuitofHappiness/dec.txt}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the output in the `.bbl` file is purely for internal use for `biblatex` and its use of the command `\verb` does not mean that this is the command that is actually used to print the field later on in the bibliography. So patching the `.bbl` to have `\path` instead of `\verb` would just break `biblatex`, but not the file paths in the bibliography.

The important thing for the output is the field format for `file`. In your setup (with the `reading` style) the definition is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\bibstring{file}\addcolon\space \url{#1}}
```

so `biblatex` uses the `\url` command from the `url` package (which it loads).

But this is not the whole story. `biblatex` has its own modification of `url`'s settings to enable a more fine-grained control over URL breaking in the bibliography. In particular `\UrlBreaks` is redefined for all URLs printed by `biblatex`. So your redefinition of `\UrlBreaks` gets overwritten.

You can get a similar result to your redefinition with `biblatex`'s built-in features by setting `biburlucpenalty` and `biburllcpenalty` to non-zero values. See also [Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134191/35864). For good measure you may also want to look into setting `biburlnumpenalty`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=reading, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{XXXXXX,
  author = {PQR},
  booktitle = {BBC},
  keywords = {LLM},
  title = {ARP},
  year = {2010},
  file = {/Users/joe/We_hold_these_truths_to_be_self-evident_that_all_men_are_created_equal_that_they_are_endowed_by_their_Creator_with_certain_unalienable_Rights_that_among_these_are_Life_Liberty_and_the_pursuit_of_Happiness/dec.txt},
}

@inproceedings{YYYYYYYY,
  author = {PQR},
  booktitle = {BBC},
  keywords = {LLM},
  title = {ARP},
  year = {2010},
  file = {/Users/joe/Weholdthesetruthstobeself-evidentthatallmenarecreatedequalthattheyareendowedbytheirCreatorwithcertainunalienableRightsthatamongtheseareLifeLibertyandthepursuitofHappiness/dec.txt},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: File paths get broken at line ends.]

---

If you don't want to use `biblatex`'s built-in features and want to carry your custom redefinition of `url`'s settings into `biblatex`, then a bit of extra work is needed.

The cheapest solution I found was

```
\newcommand*{\mkjcurlbreaks}{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks%  save the current one
    \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
    \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
    \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
    \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
    \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
    \do\Y\do\Z}}

\mkjcurlbreaks

\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\bibstring{file}\addcolon\space\mkjcurlbreaks\url{#1}}
```

An alternative approach could modify [the definition of `biblatex`'s `\biburlsetup`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L250-L274) directly.

Comment: I guess my question is technically a duplicate but thank you very much for the explanation!