# macOS problem with line breaks in citation urls - not reproducible with Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, urls, mactex

I have an issue of URLs running out of bounds on macOS in the bibliography like this:

[image]

I have tested this with the most recent versions of `mactex`. I have tested both the GUI-Version Version 4.44 (4.44) and the `mactex-no-gui` Version 2020.0407, i.e. `latexmk` Version 4.67 (on two seperate machines with macOS 10.15.5). This is the MNE (minimum non-working example) code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\cite{Vouloumanos12933}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

...with this bibliograpy `sample.bib`:

```
@article {Vouloumanos12933,
  author = {Vouloumanos, Athena and Onishi, Kristine H. and Pogue, Amanda},
  title = {Twelve-month-old infants recognize that speech can communicate unobservable intentions},
  volume = {109},
  number = {32},
  pages = {12933--12937},
  year = {2012},
  doi = {10.1073/pnas.1121057109},
  publisher = {National Academy of Sciences},
  abstract = {Much of our knowledge is acquired not from direct experience but through the speech of others. Speech allows rapid and efficient transfer of information that is otherwise not directly observable. Do infants recognize that speech, even if unfamiliar, can communicate about an important aspect of the world that cannot be directly observed: a person{\textquoteright}s intentions? Twelve-month-olds saw a person (the Communicator) attempt but fail to achieve a target action (stacking a ring on a funnel). The Communicator subsequently directed either speech or a nonspeech vocalization to another person (the Recipient) who had not observed the attempts. The Recipient either successfully stacked the ring (Intended outcome), attempted but failed to stack the ring (Observable outcome), or performed a different stacking action (Related outcome). Infants recognized that speech could communicate about unobservable intentions, looking longer at Observable and Related outcomes than the Intended outcome when the Communicator used speech. However, when the Communicator used nonspeech, infants looked equally at the three outcomes. Thus, for 12-month-olds, speech can transfer information about unobservable aspects of the world such as internal mental states, which provides preverbal infants with a tool for acquiring information beyond their immediate experience.},
  issn = {0027-8424},
  url = "https://www.pnas.org/content/109/32/12933",
  eprint = {https://www.pnas.org/content/109/32/12933.full.pdf},
  journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences}
}
```

Then I was reading different posts like [Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134191/line-breaks-of-long-urls-in-biblatex-bibliography) and tried to apply the fix. Oddly it did not work for me.

I was then reading on the overleaf.com website and tried to reproduce the issue there. As you can see here, https://www.overleaf.com/read/mpzbhzvsxndj, in overleaf the code works perfectly fine (with all 4 compilers).

This is confusing for me. Is the latex engine on macos somehow broken? Or is the overleaflatex somehow special? And most importantly how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try loading `xurl`?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you posted using the information you've provided.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! I just tried `\usepackage{xurl}`  it did not make any difference.
@Mico So its for you like in the overleaf client? It just works?

Comment: When did you last run the `tlmgr` utility? biblatex's `apa` has been updated recently.

Comment: I am running `sudo tlmgr update --self && sudo tlmgr update --all` right now. I might have missed that after the installation. Hope that will fix it!

Comment: Oh yeah. Thankfully `apa` begins with a so it is already updated and it is fixed (while the command is still running haha)!
Thanks! If you want you can put the answer up :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was fixed by running the `tlmgr` utility.

Comment: @Tillus - Glad the issue got resolved by running `tlmgr` TeXLive Manager utility.

Comment: `sudo tlmgr update --self --all`  Is the same in one turn! And you can define an alias in your local `.bash_profile`:  `alias tlupdate='tlmgr update --reinstall-forcibly-removed --all --self'` . Then a `sudo tlupdate` will be enough.

Comment: Use either the url or hyperref package.

Comment: @user187802 - What's the equivalent instruction for users of `zsh`?

Comment: On macOS use TeX Live Utility which is a front end for tlmgr.

Comment: @Mico Just add the line `alias tlupdate='tlmgr update --reinstall-forcibly-removed --all --self'` to your `~/.zshrc` instead of the `~/.bash_profile`
@HerbSchulz Thanks! The issue was already solved by updating. I will put the answer up in a second if Mico does not mind. Otherwise we could also close the question, I just do not know how that works.

Comment: @HerbSchulz `biblatex` already loads the `url` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is really simple:** @Mico told me to update all LaTeX packages by running the `tlmgr` utility.

I.e.: `$ sudo tlmgr update --self --all` (thanks to @user18702)

Crucially, this action updated the package `biblatex-apa`.