# Line breaking in hyperlinks in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, line-breaking

I have a bibliography in which I included hyperlinks to the publication sites in the bibliography. Now I would like to include a line break within the hyperlink because the references are too long.

None of the options I have found so far have worked, I would appreciate any help. Apologies, if this has an obvious solution, I'm a Latex beginner.
I am using the LaTex compiler on Overleaf.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doilink}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
    #1%
    }{%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printtext[doilink]{%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  }%
}

\addbibresource{Library.bib}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Reference 1\autocite{RN398}
\newline
Reference 2\autocite{RN404}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

and my References

```
@article{RN398,
   author = {Stabile, Paolo and Lamonica, Alessandro and Ribecai, Arianna and Castoldi, Damiano and Guercio, Giuseppe and Curcuruto, Ornella},
   journal = {Tetrahedron Lett.},
   volume = {51},
   number = {37},
   pages = {4801-4805},
   url = {10.1016/j.tetlet.2010.06.139},
   year = {2010}
}

@article{RN404,
   author = {Cordes, D. B. and Hua, G. and Slawin, A. M. and Woollins, J. D.},
   journal = {Acta Crystallogr C},
   volume = {67},
   number = {Pt 12},
   pages = {509-514},
   url = {10.1107/S0108270111049900},
   year = {2011}
}
```

Comment: This may be helpful: [Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134281/)

Comment: I had found that as well but I couldn't get it to work :/

Answer (score 1):

The following code breaks lines correctly with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

It was only slightly modified from your code to use the `doi` field instead of `url`, because `10.1016/j.tetlet.2010.06.139` is not a URL an the code links to teh DOI resolver all the time anyway.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doilink}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {#1}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printtext[doilink]{%
    \usebibmacro{author}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  }%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{RN398,
  author  = {Stabile, Paolo and Lamonica, Alessandro
             and Ribecai, Arianna and Castoldi, Damiano
             and Guercio, Giuseppe and Curcuruto, Ornella},
  journal = {Tetrahedron Lett.},
  volume  = {51},
  number  = {37},
  pages   = {4801-4805},
  doi     = {10.1016/j.tetlet.2010.06.139},
  year    = {2010},
}
@article{RN404,
  author  = {Cordes, D. B. and Hua, G. and Slawin, A. M. and Woollins, J. D.},
  journal = {Acta Crystallogr C},
  volume  = {67},
  number  = {Pt 12},
  pages   = {509-514},
  doi     = {10.1107/S0108270111049900},
  year    = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Reference 1\autocite{RN398}

Reference 2\autocite{RN404}

\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: Nicely broken lines]

Note that the screenshot does not reproduce the link boxes, but the links are there.

Just to verify that everything works as expected on Overleaf as well, follow https://www.overleaf.com/read/zvsvhcvgsbgy to see the MWE on overleaf.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. For another reason, I have to use the LaTex compiler, is there a way to get line breaks with the LaTex compiler as well?

Comment: @piggy I'm pretty sure that on the LaTeX-to-DVI route you can't get your links broken nicely. There is `\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}`, which allows links to break, but messes up the link targets. I'd look into a way to use a compiler different from LaTeX. There are ways to get `.eps` graphics into your PDF file even with pdfLaTeX for example.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into that, thanks!