# BibLaTeX line break after author name before year in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, overflow

After I figured out how to get rid of the overfull boxes due to long URLs [Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134191/line-breaks-of-long-urls-in-biblatex-bibliography), I am now trying to get rid of this one line sticking out. It is likely due to the fact that the name is very long and it tries to start the date on the same line.

I am unsure what penalty I need to set here. I am also not dead set on the way I am citing here if anyone has a better idea how to cite a stack exchange question

[image]

Comment: For general line breaking advice in the bibliography, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864. If you need help specifically for this entry, your best chance of getting useful help is sharing an example document that reproduces the undesirable line break.

Comment: In this instance I'd probably 'solve' the issue by not having the URL be part of the author's name in the bibliography.

Comment: apparently the "/robert-israel" part is fluff in this link and can be removed. This solves my problem. Found the solution in tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308 (thanks @moewe)