# URL constantly results in a badbox

Tags: hyphenation

I am trying to insert a long url into a LaTeX document. I'm using `hyperref` package to make them clickable. However, Kile constantly tells me that it results in a badbox. It is strange, since, well, these urls do not have to look good, so it could split them in any place and it would still be good. I tried a few solutions, here, on TeX exchange, using `url` package, `sloppy`, adding some manual hyphenation rule and so on. Nothing works. Sometimes it produces a different hyphenation pattern, but it is still marked by badbox.

Is there any sensible reason to do it? I want to show the whole url, btw, so link shorteners are no good (and they aren't answer anyway.)

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does [my answer to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102152/insert-hyphenation-point-in-bibtex-using-pdflatex-and-hyperref/102168#102168) answer your question?

Comment: you might try the option `breaklinks` for `hyperref`.

Comment: Since nobody knows how the urls look llike or what chars they include, it is impossible to tell anything or leading to a dublicate. There is just not enough information to give a precise answer. I vote to close as unclear.