# Lightweight xelatex

Tags: xetex, installing, miktex

On my winXP machine MikTEX installation folder is almost 500M. That's ok when I use it myself. I want to bundle installation package or pre-installed latex distribution (I need xeLaTeX especially) in my software. But pulling a 500M of stuff with my setup.exe is a bit more than I expected.

Is there any way to exclude unneeded packeges and or parts of miktex to reduce it's size, while leaving classes that I use? Or maybe get a clean latex/xelatex install and try to compile my file and let package manager get required packaged from CTAN?

Comment: Most likely the space is taken by fonts and/or package documentations. If you are using XeTeX then you don’t need most of the Type1 fonts I guess, so try first to get rid of those.

Comment: Thanks for an idea. The "doc" folder is indeed almost 150M large. The type1 fonts are just ~20M.
There is a lot of dll/exe files in miktex\bin folder and I can't find out if I need any of them. There are a lot of Qt libs and texworks files that seem unnesesary to me as long as I use command line rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first pay attention to this, please: [Redistributing MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/copying).

This said, do second:

Install either a portable MiKTeX or a basic installation in a sandbox or on a virtual drive (because this would otherwise not work together with the existing installation).

Open in this second installation the Settings/Options and …

- Go first on “Formats” tab, and exclude all formats you’re sure you will not need. Here a screenshot I made for an [older question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71460/9237):

  [image: screenshot of settings window, "Formats" tab]
- In the “Languages” tab I would not remove any language, rather add some missing ones.
- In the “Packages” tab go through all installed packages and remove the hook for all, where you are sure, they aren’t needed. In a basic installation you will have less to do as in the portable version.

After this *make **comprehensive** tests*, whether nothing important is excluded now. When you hopefully do not have changed the default “installation-on-the-fly” missing packages will be added while compiling, but missing formats have to be reenabled by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same challenge a while ago. In my case, I only needed to compile documents of a fixed format and I thus only needed a small subset of the TeX distribution. To extract this subset i wrote a script, which

- Sets up a "watch" on the TeX distribution (I used [FileSystemAuditRules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemauditrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
- Compiles all relevant file templates using the
  monitored TeX distribution.
- Copies all files accessed during
  compilation to an external destination.

Using this method I was able to get down to a working "core" of ~ 50-60 MB (~ 10 MB compressed). In my case this was a perfect solution, but if you users need to edit the documents, I would advise against using this solution as XeLaTeX (which I used) might crash hard if excluded functionality is accessed.

Comment: Could you, please, add more information about the first point? If available simply as a link to another resource (StackExchange sites highly preferred), but if you do not find a tutorial, you could add it here, too, in spite of being not TeX related.

Comment: A link to the class which I used for monitoring has been added. I am not aware of any resources discussing first point, but I might add a tutorial if the interest is there.

Comment: The problem is that it is strictly spoken off-topic here. So I hoped you could find an external link to a tutorial. You could add here some explanation, but I see you are registered on [su]. You could ask a question there and answer it immediately (can be done in one step) – and add a link to this question here.

Comment: BTW a suggestion in other cases frequently given to new users: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".