# Fatal Package fontspec Error

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia

I am working on texstudio.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\arebicfont[sript=Arabic]{Amiri}
    
    \begin{document}
        
        
        
        
        ooooo
        
    \end{document}
```

Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or(fontspec) LuaTeX. \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}

Comment: Can you please post the error message you get? How do you compile your document? Are you sure the font (Amiri) is installed on your machine?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or(fontspec) LuaTeX. \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}

Comment: Please edit your question to provide new information. Do not just put them in a comment. Also please choose a descriptive title for your question.
Have you read the error message? It seems that you are running `pdftex` instead of `xetex` or `luatex` as required by the fontspec package.

Comment: I am working on texstudio

Comment: You must use compile your document with either XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71436/fontspec-luatex-error.

Answer (score 1):

To use the fontspec package, compile your document with either XeTeX or LuaTeX.